# Diffrential equations escape velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

if $v_{e}$, denotes the escape velocity and $v_{0} < v_{e}$
projectile rises high but does not escape , show that

$$
h = {\left(v_{0}/v_{e}\right)^{2} \over 1 - \left(v_{0}/v_{e}\right)^{2}}\, R
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle{R} & \mbox{is the radius of Earth}.
\\[1mm]
\displaystyle{h}\ & \mbox{is the height that it will start to fall down.}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Here is my try:
$$
\mbox{From the energy conservation:}\quad
\frac{1}{2}\,mv^{2} - \frac{1}{2}\,mv_{0}^{2} =
\frac{GmM}{R_{0}} - \frac{GmM}{h}
$$

But here I cannot put $v_e$ in to the equation. I am not looking for an answer but for an advise to approach such a problem ?. Any help is welcome !.

Comment: Compute $h$ for $v=0$. Determine the maximum $v_0$ such that such a $h$ exists, or the supremum of those $v_0$, which should give a formula for $v_e$. -- And check the sign of the potential energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The *Energy Conservation Law* is given by:
\begin{align}
{1 \over 2}\,mv_{0}^{2} - {GMm \over R} & =
{1 \over 2}\,mv^{2} - {GMm \over R + h}\,,\qquad\mbox{where}\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
\ds{m}: & \mbox{Mass.}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\vec{v}_{0}}: & \mbox{Initial Velocity.}
\\[1mm]
\ds{G}: & \mbox{Gravitatory Constant.}
\\[1mm]
\ds{M}: & \mbox{Earth Mass.}
\\[1mm]
\ds{R}: & \mbox{Earth Radius.}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\vec{v}}: & \mbox{Velocity at height}\ \ds{R + h}\mbox{.}
\end{array}\right. \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
The *Escape Velocity* $\ds{\vec{v}_{\rm e}}$ is given by the limits
$\ds{\pars{~h \to \infty\,,\ v \to 0\,,\ v_{0} \to v_{\rm e}} \implies
v_{\rm e} = \sqrt{2GM \over R}~}$.

---

\begin{equation}
\mbox{Energy Conservation Law \eqref{1} becomes:}\quad
v_{0}^{2} = v_{\rm e}^{2} + v^{2} - {R \over R + h}\,v_{\rm e}^{2}
\end{equation}
The maximum value of $\ds{h\ \pars{h_{\rm max}}}$ is given by the limit $\ds{\pars{~v \to 0\,,\ h \to h_{\rm max}~}}$
$$
v_{0}^{2} =
v_{\rm e}^{2}  - {R \over R + h_{max}}\,v_{\rm e}^{2}
\quad\implies\quad
\bbox[8px,border:0.1em groove navy]{h_{\rm max} =
{\pars{v_{0}/v_{\rm e}}^{2} \over 1 - \pars{v_{0}/v_{\rm e}}^{2}}\, R}
$$